# Critical Regex Implementation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure if this can be done in SQL Server. May someone please help me if possible with SQL?

I have a table with data looks like this:

```
DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE
(
    ColumnA VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT INTO @MYTABLE
    SELECT '01268 591558 * 3 Marina' UNION ALL
    SELECT '01322 421980    JULIE  A/P' UNION ALL
    SELECT '01296620096 BR TAKES CARD EOM' UNION ALL
    SELECT '07547 740863/07986 019852' UNION ALL
    SELECT '07754553528 - TIM' UNION ALL
    SELECT '07732418595 sam' UNION ALL
    SELECT '01793 425574- Charlotte' UNION ALL
    SELECT '01268 591558 * 3 Marina' UNION ALL
    SELECT '07967 967404 CELIA' UNION ALL
    SELECT '0208 361 1213 / 1433      /8899 ' UNION ALL   
    SELECT '0208 361 1213 / 1433 '  UNION ALL        
    SELECT '0208 361 1213 / 1433'  UNION ALL         
    SELECT '01206 578671 / 564272' UNION ALL
    SELECT '01206735561/07748116152' UNION ALL
    SELECT '0208 361 1213 / 1433  '  UNION ALL       
    SELECT '01234 754047   SUE' UNION ALL
    SELECT '01206735561/07748116152/0156589'
```

and I am expecting output like

[image]

May someone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Cleaning up your phone numbers is a hard task that is not well-suited for SQL.  This would be hard, even with regular expression matching.

Comment: To add to what Gordon said, SQL does not support regular expressions. There is some support for _limited_ pattern matching, but SQL is not the right tool for the task you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: This data is such a mess that it is going to be incredibly challenging in any language to clean this up automatically.

Comment: @SeanLange: You are absolutely right Sean

Comment: Not sure how many rows you have in your actual table but I would venture to say that it would likely take more time to write up automated solution than it would to just fix the data manually. And in this case a manual solution is far more likely to get the results correct. :)

Comment: @SeanLange: 65k Records........... a nightmare :)

Comment: For 65K records you just need to get a temp worker in for a week - maybe knock them up a quick UI for working through the records one-by-one...

Comment: That's not going to be fun. Writing a utility in dotnet or some other programming language that can more readily handle looping and such is probably a good solution for something like this. Or find somebody in house that can help.

Comment: @SeanLange: Thanks Sean....... will it be possible with C#

Comment: Of course it is possible. You can do it with t-sql too. It is just time and money to build you the solution you need. The biggest challenge is defining all the rules needs to parse this.

Comment: @SeanLange: Thanks Sean:i will start now..... summing up all rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works with the sample data, but there are some potential pitfalls.

Currently the XML will split up to 9 positions (easy to expand or contract).

Clearly you could add more ColumnX if needed.  Just follow the pattern

**Example**

```
Select A.*
      ,Column1 = left(Pos1,11)
      ,Column2 = case when Try_Convert(float,Pos2) is null then null else Left(Pos1,11-Len(Pos2))+Pos2 end
      ,Column3 = case when Try_Convert(float,Pos3) is null then null else Left(Pos1,11-Len(Pos3))+Pos3 end
From @MYTABLE A
Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos6 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos7 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos8 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos9 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(A.ColumnA,' ',''),'/','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as C
            ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: @RohiniMathur Happy it helped

Comment: Hi John, the suggested solution is working awesome, is it possible to bypass this error which i am getting when tested against production database. "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function." Please help

Comment: @RohiniMathur Give me a moment to take a peek at it

Comment: @RohiniMathur Having trouble creating an error.  I inserted bogus values into your sample data ... NULL, {blank}, aaa, and 99    any insight as to the type of string causing the error?

Comment: Give me a moment please.

Comment: 40 million records. not able to find out yet. still trying :(

Comment: @RohiniMathur many things can go wrong in 40 million records.  Let me noodle it a bit more

Comment: Thanks a lotttttttt .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135873/discussion-between-rohini-mathur-and-john-cappelletti).